# Does Apple Pay in an iOS app require a payment's handler like Stripe?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

If I accept payments via Apple Pay within my app for goods sold on my app do I need to also set up a Stripe account or will Apple handle the payments directly?

Comment: For Apple Pay you need to set up a merchant agreement with a payment processor, such as Stripe.  These are physical goods delivere outside the app yes?

Comment: Yes, physical goods outside the app. So I would have to work with a company like Stripe then?

Comment: Yes, you will need a company like stripe to process your payments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We must need any merchant like Stripe, Braintree, mastercard etc. to perform actual payment.